# Nested objects in Swashbuckle auto-generated example

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a .NET Core API that is documented via Swashbuckle and Swagger. The "example" that is generated for the UI doesn't seem to be including nested objects in the request properly, although they are handled and processed correctly when executing the endpoints.

I have a `CreatePaymentRequest` class, which is received from the body of the HTTP request, which contains a property of a `Notional` type. `Notional` is made up of a `decimal` value, and a `string` value.

The generated example looks like this:

```
{
  "tradeId": 0,
  "settlementMeans": "SWIFT",
  "notional1": {},
  "notional1Rate": 0,
  "notional2": {},
  "notional2Rate": 0,
  "paymentReference": "string",
  "description": "string"
}
```

When I would expect it to look like this:

```
{
  "tradeId": 0,
  "settlementMeans": "SWIFT",
  "notional1": {"Amount": 0, "Currency": "string"},
  "notional1Rate": 0,
  "notional2": {"Amount": 0, "Currency": "string"},
  "notional2Rate": 0,
  "paymentReference": "string",
  "description": "string"
}
```

The generated schema also seems to be off, as it doesn't include the properties for `Notional`:
[image]

Though it is listed properly in the "Schemas" section at the bottom:
[image]

Here are the classes that make up each object:

```
public class Request
{
    public long TradeId { get; set; }
    public SettlementMeans SettlementMeans { get; set; }
    public Notional Notional1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Notional1Rate { get; set; }
    public Notional Notional2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Notional2Rate { get; set; }
    public string PaymentReference { get; set; } = "";
    public string Description { get; set; } = "";
}

public class Notional
{
    [JsonContructor]
    public Notional(decimal amount, string currency)
    {
        Amount = amount;
        Currency = currency;
    }

    public Notional()
    {
        Amount = 0;
        Currency = "XXX";
    }

    public decimal Amount { get; }
    public string Currency { get; }
}
```

Controller method:

```
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(CreatePaymentApi_Response))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(BadRequestResponse))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<ActionResult<CreatePaymentApi_Response>> PostCreate(CreatePaymentApi_Request request)
{
    var command = _mapper.Map<CreatePaymentHandler.Request>(request);
    var response = await _mediator.Send(command);
    var result = _mapper.Map<CreatePaymentHandler.Response>(response);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

I am setting up SwaggerGen using `services.AddSwaggerGen();` in `ConfigureServices` without any special options.

Having to constantly type out, or copy / paste the JSON for the `Notional` values is starting to become very repetitive when debugging via the Swashbuckle UI. Is there anything I can do to get the example to generate as I expect it to?

Comment: Hi @Bradley Uffner, what is the version of your swagger and asp.net core? I have tested in asp.net 5, and it works as expected with the nested model.

Comment: It is .Net 5, using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.2.4, and NSwag.ApiDescription.Client 13.11.3

Comment: Hi @Bradley Uffner, are you sure you use  Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.2.4 in .net 5?  There is even no such version for Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. Why do you use `NSwag.ApiDescription.Client ` ?  Besides, could you please share your Startup.cs?

Comment: That's a VERY good question...  I just went back to verify the version numbers, and They are completely different than I remember.  I must have been looking in the wrong place previously. It is actually using just `<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />`, on `.net5.0`. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I have to say it is so amazing. I use the same version with your nuget package. Maybe you need create a new .net 5 project and try again.  Not sure if you did any other configuration that make nested model does not work.

Comment: Yes, I'll try from scratch.  This solution was actually created by someone else and handed off to me.  There may be some things hiding elsewhere in the solution that are affecting the API generation. Hopefully I can work out what that is and apply it back to this project.  Thank you for your assistance, I really appreciate the time you have spent helping me.

Comment: I was eventually able to track the problem down to lack of full support for `System.text.Json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to track this down to the readonly `Amount` and `Currency` properties on `Notional`.  I was expecting it to use the constructor marked with `JsonConstructor`, but apparently, this is only supported when using the newtonsoft serializer, NOT `System.Text.Json`.

In theory, I should be able to work around this using a custom `ISchemaFilter`, but I've decided that it isn't worth it just yet to implement one.

Comment: If anyone ever comes across this, facing the same issue, add XML doc to swagger gen